# Difference of chi-squared distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This question seems simple, but it gets me a little confused.

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are independent and $U\sim \chi_k^2$ and $W=U+V \sim \chi_{k+l}^2$. Can we then immediately say that $V\sim \chi_l^2$?

It is clear that if $V\sim \chi_l^2$ then $U+V \sim \chi_{k+l}^2$. But can we be sure that this is the only solution to the distribution of $V$?

Comment: yes. this is correct.

Comment: Maybe use the uniqueness of MGFs as a proof.